# gitで異なるコミットリビジョンの異なるファイルをDIFFするには？

Tags: git

異なるコミットリビジョンの同一ファイルは、DIFFできることを知っているのですが、
renameなどでファイルパスが変わったコミットとその前のコミットで、
ファイルのDIFFをする方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Git2.9](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L33-L34)よりリネーム検知がデフォルトで有効になりました。

[The GitHub Blog](https://github.com/blog/2188-git-2-9-has-been-released) より:

> Rename detection is now enabled by default for diffs.[中略]
>   Git infers on the fly when a file has been renamed by looking for similarities between the contents of the old and new files.

従って最近のバージョンであれば `git diff HEAD~2` のような実行で所望の結果になっていると思います。

特定のファイルの差分が知りたい場合には、依然としてリネーム前のファイル名も指定する必要がありそうです。
`git diff HEAD~2 HEAD -- moe.txt moemoe.txt`

---

古いバージョンでは `git diff -M HEAD~2` のように `-M` オプションが必要です。

[GIT-DIFF(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> -M[<n>], --find-renames[=<n>]
>   Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index [後略]

Answer (score 3):

ファイル名を指定することで差分を取得できます。

例:

```
git diff HEAD\~2:moe.txt HEAD:moemoe.txt
```